# Default Port for Spice in QEMU

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtualization, qemu, arm64, libvirt

I'm virtualizating Ubuntu and other `aarch64` Operating Systems on my KVM-enabled Raspberry Pi 4 (running *Ubuntu Desktop 21.04*). I've successfully enabled OpenGL acceleration in my *aarch64 Ubuntu 20.04* guest, using the QEMU arguments `--virtio-gpu,virgl=on --display sdl,gl=on`. However instead of using SDL to render the window, I want to use Spice. The following would do this:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 --M virt --enable-kvm --cpu host --m 2G \
--bios /usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd \
--device usb-ehci --device usb-kbd \
--spice disable-ticketing,gl=on,addr=127.0.0.1,port=3001 \
--device virtio-gpu,virgl=on
```

(here's an example you can reproduce with an `x64` system)

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --M pc-q35 --enable-kvm --cpu host --m 2G \
--device usb-ehci --device usb-kbd \
--spice disable-ticketing,gl=on,addr=127.0.0.1,port=3001 \
--device virtio-gpu,virgl=on
```

but returns `SPICE GL support is local-only for now and incompatible with -spice port/tls-port`.

When I omit the `port=3001` in the `--spice` argument, it does not throw the error, however I do not know how to connect to this new VM. Using `--display spice-app` does not work because Ubuntu's `virt-viewer` version is `7.0`, instead of the necessary `8.0`. Therefore, I tried using `remote-viewer` (bundled with `virt-manager`) and I couldn't connect to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, even if I tried using ports like `3000, 3001, 5900, 5901`.

So, what port do I need to (locally) connect to my VM through `remote-viewer`? My VM is running on my Raspberry Pi 4, and I want to connect to it through that same Pi 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option "gl=on" and "port=..." are incompatible, this was introduce in this [commit](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/569a93cbbe428bb5c583ae4bf31447eb3acc30fe)
The comment explains virtlg use a unix socket and thus is not compatible with remote access.

However you can connect locally, starting qemu with :

```
 --spice disable-ticketing,gl=on,unix,addr=/tmp/spice.sock
```

And then connect locally using :

```
remote-viewer spice+unix:///tmp/spice.sock
```